# Getting NaN from form PHP form using JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, nan

I'm getting a NaN value if i try to do any math with the two vars i pull form the form. It also gives me NaN if i try it parseInt it. IDK if it helps but the values are pulled from the URL using PHP; example: `.../serch.php?animal=all&color=any&sunSd=all&lifeSpn=all&limiterF=5&limiterT=20`

limiterF and limiterT are the vars I'm working with.
html:

```
<form id='serchForm' action="serch.php" method="GET">
...
            <fieldset>
            From: <input type='text' id = 'limiterFid' name='limiterF' value=<?php if (!empty($_GET['limiterF'])) {echo $limiterF;} else {echo 0;} ?> size="2" /><br />
            To: <input type='text' id = 'limiterTid' name='limiterT' value=<?php if (!empty($_GET['limiterT'])) {echo $limiterT;} else {echo 20;} ?>  size="2" />
            </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="submitNew" />
        <input type="submit" id="nextSerch" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#serchForm input").click(function(e) {
        if(e.target.id == 'submitNew') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#limiterFid').attr("value", 0);
            $('#limiterTid').attr("value", 20);
            $("#serchForm").submit();
        } else if (e.target.id == 'nextSerch') {
            e.preventDefault();
            var limiterF = $('#limiterFid').value,
            limiterT = $('#limiterTid').value;
            limiterT = limiterF + limiterT;
            limiterF = parseInt(limiterF, 5);

            $('#limiterFid').attr("value", limiterF);
            $('#limiterTid').attr("value", limiterT);
            $("#serchForm").submit();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

This is what it will return when you click nextSerch:

```
.../serch.php?animal=all&color=any&sunSd=all&lifeSpn=all&limiterF=NaN&limiterT=NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value` is a property of the DOM element not the jQuery object. You can use either `val()` or `value` on the original DOM element.

```
$('element').val()
// OR
$('element')[0].value
```

Also to set values you typically don't use `attr`, you use `val`.

```
$('element').val('newValue')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method, as `value` will returned undefined as it is attempting to call the 'value' property of a jQuery object:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#serchForm input").click(function(e) {
        if(e.target.id == 'submitNew') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#limiterFid').val(0);
            $('#limiterTid').val(20);
            $("#serchForm").submit();
        } else if (e.target.id == 'nextSerch') {
            e.preventDefault();
            var limiterF = $('#limiterFid').val(),
            limiterT = $('#limiterTid').val();
            limiterT = limiterF + limiterT;
            limiterF = parseInt(limiterF, 5);

            $('#limiterFid').val(limiterF);
            $('#limiterTid').val(limiterT);
            $("#serchForm").submit();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's always the little things like that I seem to spend the most time on.